# How to Find particular column ,In that particular cell in RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am  new in  using  telerik rad Grid,I have requirement like  this

### Column1 | Column2

### java    | check Box

### .Net    | check Box

### Python  | check Box

Like this ,The above one is existing  "Rad Grid" having two columns , I want to know In  Column2  which check box is checked.,using the 
allowMultipleRowSelection="true"..,how to find that a particular Check box is checked or Not.
**Eg:-**
 ***.Net*** Row checked Box  is checked  just assume

how to find that particular check-box of that **.net** Row,In

Insert And Update ,But it's inside other grid not an Independent grid.
Parent Grid Insert Or Update I need to Find out that particular one.

please give reply...if any one Knows.

```
                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RgList1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                        ShowHeader="false" Width="148px"  >
                        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" >

                        <Columns>

                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("BankTypeName")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                             </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                             <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="chkBankList1">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBankTypeName" runat="server"  />
                             </ItemTemplate>

                            </Columns>
                        </MasterTableView>
     <ClientSettings  AllowColumnsReorder="true" EnableRowHoverStyle="true"   > 
                          <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true"/>
                        </ClientSettings>  

                    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: on which event you want to check?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ItemDataBound event of RgList1.  This method fires for each item in the grid.  Once there, you can use an if statement or a switch statement to check e.Item.ItemType.  This is an enumerator - you'll see lots of options there like Item, AlternatingItem, EditItem, FooterItem, etc.

Then you can use FindControl to find your checkbox.

Try casting e.Item as GridDataItem

```
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
{
    var item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    CheckBox chkBankTypeName = (CheckBox)item["chkBankList1"].FindControl("chkBankTypeName");
}
```

Comment: Thanks  ,But I need how to access the cells  like this  rglist1.Mastertableview.column[1].something to get the whether check Box ix checked or Not . In .aspx.cs Page .

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in RgList1.MasterTableView.Items)
{
   CheckBox chkBankTypeName = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkBankTypeName");
   if (chkBankTypeName != null && chkBankTypeName.Checked)
   {
            // Do your logic here
   }
}
```

Note : There is not any relation with  allowMultipleRowSelection="true" and asp:CheckBox in RadGrid.

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks Friend...It's Very useful.....I am Seen many post  Previously your  ...answered ones,  Thanks Once  Again.